# How to make down arrow on VSCode to go to end of line in Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm starting to use VSCode to work with Jupyter Notebooks (I've been using Google Colab before), and the thing that most annoys me is that when I'm at the last line of a cell and press the down arrow, nothing happens. In Google Colab, when you press the down button in the last line, it goes to the end of the line, and it makes me code much faster.

I know that VSCode has a lot of possibilities for customization and configuration, but I don´t have the knowledge for it. Is there a way to change that behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Pressing Ctrl+Down goes to the end of the line, and Ctrl+Up is for the start.
For more detailed keyboard shortcuts in VS Code, go to the article Visual [Studio Code Key Bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor)

Comment: By `up`, do you mean the `uparrow`?

Answer (score 1):

For cursor to go from the beginning of the last line to the end of it when pressing arrow down (↓) instead of jumping to the next cell you should open Keyboard Shortcuts (**File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts** [Ctrl+K Ctrl+S]) and remove or change bindings for "**Notebook: Focus Next Cell Editor**". Similarly you should change bindings for "**Notebook: Focus Previous Cell Editor**" if you want the same functionality for the up arrow (↑).

Answer (score 0):

Ashikur's solution is now out of date, unfortunately. `ctrl+downarrow` is no longer bound to `cursorLineEnd` but to `notebook.focusNextEditor`. In order to have `ctrl+downarrow` go to end of line, you have to add it as a shortcut in the vscode keybindings tool, and remove the current keybinding for `notebook.focusNextEditor`.

I spent a while trying to figure out if there is a way to implement exactly the same functionality as the old Jupyter, where the down arrow moves to the end of the line if you are on the last line of a cell. Unfortunately, this would require vscode to have a [context key](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts) for when the cursor is at the end of the line, which apparently it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution in the latest version of VSCode. File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts [Ctrl+K Ctrl+S]) and remove or change bindings for "Notebook: Focus Next Cell Editor". In the key bindings change all focus next cell editor to cmd+'down arrow'. Problem solved! I have not seen any problem with the change where I replaced "down arrow" with cmd+'down arrow'. If I see any problem, I will modify it [image]further.

Answer (score 0):

Since version [1.82](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_82), vscode has context key for line boundary (`notebookEditorCursorAtLineBoundary`), so such behavior is now possible using these custom keybindings:

```
{
  "key": "down",
  "command": "notebook.focusNextEditor",
  "when": "config.notebook.navigation.allowNavigateToSurroundingCells && editorTextFocus && inputFocus && notebookEditorFocused && !accessibilityModeEnabled && !isEmbeddedDiffEditor && notebookEditorCursorAtBoundary == 'bottom' && notebookEditorCursorAtLineBoundary == 'end'"
}
{
  "key": "up",
  "command": "notebook.focusPreviousEditor",
  "when": "config.notebook.navigation.allowNavigateToSurroundingCells && editorTextFocus && inputFocus && notebookEditorFocused && !accessibilityModeEnabled && !isEmbeddedDiffEditor && notebookEditorCursorAtBoundary == 'top' && notebookEditorCursorAtLineBoundary == 'start'"
}
{
  "key": "down",
  "command": "cursorLineEnd",
  "when": "notebookEditorCursorAtBoundary == 'bottom' && notebookEditorCursorAtLineBoundary == 'none'"
}
{
  "key": "up",
  "command": "cursorLineStart",
  "when": "notebookEditorCursorAtBoundary == 'top' && notebookEditorCursorAtLineBoundary == 'none'"
}
```

First two items are sligtly modified default bindings, last two I had to add myself.